# How to verify a signature in a Pallet?

Tags: pallet, cryptography, offchain

I have a Pallet that should verify a signature for some input data and a specific public key.
It looks like this:

```
fn verify(_: OriginFor<T>, data: Vec<u8>, sig: ???, from: ???)
```

Is this possible? What kind of signature schemes can I use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Substrate provides a [Verify](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/latest/sp_runtime/traits/trait.Verify.html) and an [IdentifyAccount](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/latest/sp_runtime/traits/trait.IdentifyAccount.html) trait.
They work with any signature scheme since they are just traits and can be implemented for different crypto schemata.
This is very helpful when implementing off-chain protocols like Channels, Plasmas, Rollups etc.

The `Config` trait of your pallet needs to be extended to support it:

```rust
/// A Signature can be verified with a specific `PublicKey`.
type Signature: Verify<Signer = Self::PublicKey> + Encode + Decode + Parameter;

/// A PublicKey can be converted into an `AccountId`. This is required by the
/// `Signature` type.
type PublicKey: IdentifyAccount<AccountId = Self::PublicKey> + Encode + Decode + Parameter;
```

This makes it possible to verify signatures within the pallet.
Using it in an Extrinsic looks like this:

```rust
fn my_verify(_: OriginFor<T>, data: Vec<u8>, sig: T::Signature, from: T::PublicKey)
{
    let ok = sig.verify(&data, &from);
    // `ok` is a bool. Use in an `if` or `ensure!`.
}
```

On the runtime side you can then inject the *concrete* crypto implementation that you want:

```rust
type Signature = sp_core::ecdsa::Signature;
type PublicKey = sp_core::ecdsa::Public;
```

Available are `ecdsa`, `sr25519` and `ed25519` all from [sp_core](https://docs.rs/sp-core/latest/sp_core/).
The Merline signing context for `sr25519` is `b"substrate"` as defined [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/bfc6fb4a95adccf96dadbe5e5e6bb8605d5a2c01/primitives/core/src/sr25519.rs#L61).

Here are three examples in pallets that make use of this:

- [pallet-nfts](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/166ae5ae1295c2431c83421439c3869d4f40de7e/substrate/frame/nfts/src/lib.rs#L197-L205): to verify pre-mined signatures.
- [pallet-identity](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/f574868822d5976219d391de5acd66bb773e4964/substrate/frame/identity/src/lib.rs#L178-L184): to verify pre-authorized usernames.
- [perun-polkadot-pallet](https://github.com/perun-network/perun-polkadot-pallet/blob/9ef1476028ae53011f51ed7f55bdbfb8f4fc82a7/src/lib.rs#L103-L108): to verify signatures from an off-chain state channel.

Comment: That's a great one, but I thinking adding "from a pallet" to the question's title would be more assertive. Other than that, based on the title only, users can verify signatures quickly using the PolkadotJS `Developer -> Sign and Verify -> Verify Signature`.

Comment: Yes thanks! Will update it. I actually used PolkadotJS to debug my signature code 

Comment: I am not familiar with how verification works, but as far as I am aware, you need to verify that certain data X was signed by a certain private key to produce signed data Y, so you run that verification process using their pubkey to produce X'. but you still need X to prove X == X' right? So where is the field that includes the original data that was signed over?

Comment: Signatures and Encryption have theirs keys switched. Encryption uses the Public key to encode, Signatures use the Private key to sign. So to verify a Signature, you only need to know the Public key. Signing works like this `SIG = sign(PrivateKey, DATA)` and verifying `ok = verify(PublicKey, DATA, SIG)`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also see fully integrated examples of signature verification in a Pallet with:

1. The `claims` pallet, which verifies Ethereum Signatures

```
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
    // Constructs the message that Ethereum RPC's `personal_sign` and `eth_sign` would sign.
    fn ethereum_signable_message(what: &[u8], extra: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
        let prefix = T::Prefix::get();
        let mut l = prefix.len() + what.len() + extra.len();
        let mut rev = Vec::new();
        while l > 0 {
            rev.push(b'0' + (l % 10) as u8);
            l /= 10;
        }
        let mut v = b"\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n".to_vec();
        v.extend(rev.into_iter().rev());
        v.extend_from_slice(&prefix[..]);
        v.extend_from_slice(what);
        v.extend_from_slice(extra);
        v
    }

    // Attempts to recover the Ethereum address from a message signature signed by using
    // the Ethereum RPC's `personal_sign` and `eth_sign`.
    fn eth_recover(s: &EcdsaSignature, what: &[u8], extra: &[u8]) -> Option<EthereumAddress> {
        let msg = keccak_256(&Self::ethereum_signable_message(what, extra));
        let mut res = EthereumAddress::default();
        res.0
            .copy_from_slice(&keccak_256(&secp256k1_ecdsa_recover(&s.0, &msg).ok()?[..])[12..]);
        Some(res)
    }

...
```

2. The `crowdloan` pallet which verifies multiple different kinds of signatures using the `Multisignature` type:

```
if let Some(ref verifier) = fund.verifier {
    let signature = signature.ok_or(Error::<T>::InvalidSignature)?;
    let payload = (index, &who, old_balance, value);
    let valid = payload.using_encoded(|encoded| {
        signature.verify(encoded, &verifier.clone().into_account())
    });
    ensure!(valid, Error::<T>::InvalidSignature);
}
```

Comment: Reference for the mentioned `claims` pallet: polkadot's [runtime/common/src/claims.rs#L532](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/dfa8c5ae321e0523f88fdc43afc6d743812ee49e/runtime/common/src/claims.rs#L532)