# What informations consist of a signature which is generated when siging a transaction payload offline?

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsic, signed-extensions, typescript, ecdsa

From the wiki (https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-transaction-construction),

```
import { createSignedTx } from "@substrate/txwrapper-polkadot";

// Example code, replace `signWithAlice` with actual remote signer.
// An example is given here:
// https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/b213cabf50f18f0fe710817072a81596e1a53cae/packages/txwrapper-core/src/test-helpers/signWithAlice.ts
const signature = await signWithAlice(signingPayload);
console.log(signature);

const signedTx = createSignedTx(unsigned, signature, { metadataRpc, registry });
```

The printed **signature** is simply a hash string like "0x01b0e5778f36fd4c5adea875a5cd88b0da246154798fec28c5d1b4b2446d7b2028c46a423bd9706d26525706386d2dc34062bf83086db5178334d9da5016f2e684"

Question 1: I would like to know whether  we could decrypt this hash string to see what informations consist of this **signature**. i.e whether Polkadot.js APIs supports this decryption.

From the test code (https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/074e790bfc1326cda331b795b3a1e8e480493246/packages/types/src/extrinsic/v4/Extrinsic.spec.ts#L71), we can partly guess some of informations included in **signature**.

Question 2: From this test code, I would like to know what each data represents as you see below and where we could find how such hash strings are derived depending on the chosen cryptogrphy (ECDSA, Sr25519, or Ed25519). Particularly I look for source code for ECDSA signature.

```
'0x' + 
'00' + // ?
'd172a74cda4c865912c32ba0a80a57ae69abae410e5ccb59dee84e2f4432db4f' + // ?
'00' + // ed25519 (00) ; sr25519 (01) ; ECDSA (02) 
'eb58b10100923b73df92010db6f9363300ea3947d4c7c92ce669da93931853e8' + // ?  
'a2f21c8a7c73035b3ddd8cdd47ef5db3092aad09d15e6f5ed9d32d7864821409' + // ? 
'00040800' + // era 
'0600' + // nonce 
'00' + // tip 
'd7568e5f0a7eda67a82691ff379ac4bba4f9c9b859fe779b5d46363b61ad2db9' + // ?
'e56c' // ?
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could advise me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the second question I suggest you check the code of library @polkadot/util-crypto, the library that PolkadotJS uses to sign/verify.
Follow the [signatureVerify](https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/blob/1f8b573d811ebc00f078cc9ad0a96b0d5476b13d/packages/util-crypto/src/signature/verify.ts#L90), where it checks what kind of signature is to know how to verify it.

In your case ECDSA, the code source code to verify the signature is here [secp256k1Verify](https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/blob/1f8b573d81/packages/util-crypto/src/secp256k1/verify.ts#L16) and to sign [secp256k1Sign](https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/blob/1f8b573d81/packages/util-crypto/src/secp256k1/sign.ts) where you can see how the couple (,) of the ECDSA signature are concatenated.

Is a code in Rust but it can also be useful for you to check this old answer on StackExchange: [Recover ECDSA pub key from signature](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1419/2762).

Comment: Thank you for several nice links. I look for the next function which generates a **signature** (consisting of all informations in Question 2 above) with the value (concatenating r and s values) returned from [secp256k1Sign function](https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/blob/1f8b573d811ebc00f078cc9ad0a96b0d5476b13d/packages/util-crypto/src/secp256k1/sign.ts#L19). Thanks