# Why is it that the signature created using polkadot api is valid, but verifying that signature using substrate library is invalid?

Tags: polkadot-js

The js code uses polkadot api, util-crypto and extension-dap

```js
    const { signature } = await signRaw({
        address: account.address,
        data: payload,
        type: 'bytes'
    });
    // isValid is true
    const isValid = await signatureVerify(payload, signature, account.address);
```

The rust code crates the payload and passed it has hex_encoded into the js code.
I make sure that hex encoding and decoding was all correct, but I couldn't understand why the signature is valid in js code, but verifying it in the rust code against the payload returns invalid.

```rust
    let is_valid1 = signature.verify(payload.as_slice(), &signer_address);
    // invalid
    let message = format!("rust signature is valid1: {}", is_valid1);
```

Comment: Is it fixed by [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4225/94)?

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi OMG! why is this so hack. Wrapping the payload with Bytes tag, I was indeed able to verify that the signature is thus valid, but now the payload is different, and submitting the derived extrinsic and signature into the substrate node still gets rejected. Is there a way to use polkadot signature with the the Wrapping <Bytes>?

Comment: Okay then I think we can close this as duplicate. I don't know if PolkadotJS can be used without `Bytes`, I don't hope so since that would be a security issue. Why can you not wrap the message in  `Bytes` before verifying?

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi Wrapping the payload with <Bytes> to verify that the signature is fine in this case, since I have control on this part of the code. But submitting the actual signature as an extrinsic into the substrate node will be rejected with an Invalid Signature, since it has another verification step where I don't wish to change the code in that part.