# Substrate | SignatureInvalid when I try to verify signature with public key

Tags: subkey

When I try to verify a signature using Alice address I got a `SignatureInvalid` message.

```
echo "blabla" | ./target/release/subkey verify
102f4f19773b0157c87561b9b6bfa07558246cbe0155a74ffd8f6365d4d14865a92f58a928b504dd6dd392b67e8a52a58832822c3f1b89f262f1921a286f8c8 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY


Error: SignatureInvalid
```

Any help is welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you doing the signature?
Following the account generated in the example from the docs https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/subkey/

You can create a signature of a message:

```
echo "blabla" | ./target/release/subkey sign --suri 0xc8fa03532fb22ee1f7f6908b9c02b4e72483f0dbd66e4cd456b8f34c6230b849
```

It gives you this result:

```
c4273e58b19b582330577f380041171d7aa9def2922e492e1b5510bc17a03f3fe19ae2b4f8089a7b4ba821fabffb97596245aa6caecf686a9ff119010374af8f
```

That then you can validate with its corresponding account: `5Gv8YYFu8H1btvmrJy9FjjAWfb99wrhV3uhPFoNEr918utyR`

```
echo "blabla" | ./target/release/subkey verify c4273e58b19b582330577f380041171d7aa9def2922e492e1b5510bc17a03f3fe19ae2b4f8089a7b4ba821fabffb97596245aa6caecf686a9ff119010374af8f 5Gv8YYFu8H1btvmrJy9FjjAWfb99wrhV3uhPFoNEr918utyR
```

And the result is ok:

```
Signature verifies correctly.
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, how we can sign this data inside a pallet ? you think it is a good idea to sign and store some data regarding some busniss logic or it is a bad idea to do so ?

Comment: you can verify it on the pallet, see this old question https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/305/how-to-verify-a-signature-in-a-pallet

Comment: the sign has to be done offchain

Comment: Thanks, still dont know how i can sign a bunch of data inside a pallet ?

Comment: Ok thank you Alex i got the idea

Comment: Not sure if sign is the best idea, as you need the private key.

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue