# How to verify a signature of a playload in Substrate when the provided Public Key bytes are not associated with an Account?

Tags: ed25519, signatures

I have defined an extrinsic function as follows

```rust
#[pallet::call_index(0)]
        #[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::create_record())]
        pub fn create_record(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            issuer_account: T::AccountId,
            input: Data<T::PublicKeySize, T::SignatureSize>,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            let _who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
             
            let generated_public_key_from_bytes = Public::from_slice(&input.public_key)
                .map_err(|_| Error::<T>::InvalidPublicKey)?;

            let generated_signature_from_bytes = Signature::from_slice(&input.signature).ok_or(Error::<T>::InvalidSignature)?;

         

            let is_signature_valid = generated_public_key_from_bytes
                .verify(&input.public_key, &generated_signature_from_bytes)
                .is_ok();


                // more code here

                Ok(())
}
```

When I try to call `verify` function it says its not found. Im using polkadot version `0.9.42` This public key is an ED25519 Key ,

The errors which Im getting

error[E0599]: no method named `verify` found for struct `sp_core::ecdsa::Public` in the current scope

and gives this suggestion

```
help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
    |
32  +     use frame_support::sp_runtime::sp_application_crypto::RuntimePublic;
```

But its none existing path

Tried importing

```
 use sp_runtime::traits::Verify;
```

and

```
    use sp_runtime::RuntimeAppPublic;
```

separately, but there is no luck

Im getting the same error if I use `use sp_core::ed25519`

I have referred to this [How to verify a signature in a Pallet?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/305/how-to-verify-a-signature-in-a-pallet) but it was not helpful in this scenario

How to call verify function to check the signature?

Answer (score 1):

try importing `sp_runtime::RuntimeAppPublic` it has the [verify](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/trait.RuntimeAppPublic.html#tymethod.verify) method

Comment: Gets the same error      .verify(&input.public_key, &generated_signature_from_bytes)
    | |                 -^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Public` due to unsatisfied trait bounds

Comment: @not0x12 try adding also  `use sp_runtime::app_crypto::RuntimePublic;` this should work